# For Bootstrap data-toggle="toggle" preventing onClick Function,

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For Bootstrap data-toggle="toggle" preventing `onClick` Function, When I use bootstrap toggle in my code, my default `checkbox` `onclick` function not working but when I remove  `data-toggle="toggle"` this function then its works fine.

```html
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <span id="val">value</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="approval"  type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" onclick="Approve(this)">
  </div>



  <script>
    function Approve(e) {
   document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = e.checked;
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Anyone can help me please

Comment: Just so you know for the next time you ask questions: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation is likely that Bootstrap is overwriting the default event handler on your element. I can't say for certain, but that sounds to be the case.

A better way to set event handlers to elements in general is to use javascript addEventListener. remove the onclick attribute from your HTML, so it looks like this:

```
<input id="approval"  type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
```

and set the event handler on the element using javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('approval').parentNode.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // the value of `this` here is the element the event was fired on. 
    // In this situation, it's the element with the ID of 'approval'.
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = this.querySelector('input').checked
  })
</script>
```

The script section above replaces your script tag entirely, as it sets the innerHTML inside the event handler directly.

Comment: again same problem, when i use data-toggle="toggle" its not working, :(

Comment: @TanvirHossain My code example works now. Here's a jsfiddle seeing it in action if you're curious: https://jsfiddle.net/1heh7nxr/

Comment: thanks mate for your concern, i tried with extra closing at the end of the addEventListener. your code is works fine, :)  but for some reason Bootstrap toggle not working..

Comment: @TanvirHossain Ah, my apologies. I didn't take into account how the bootstrap toggle plugin changes the DOM. Updating my answer now with a script that works.

Comment: @TanvirHossain the script section now works as expected.  Keep in mind querySelector does have certain browser requirements, and may not work everywhere.  Also I couldn't get the code formatted pefectly. But it does work with the bootstrap-toggle plugin now: https://jsfiddle.net/1heh7nxr/2/  even though it looks ugly, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. After experimenting for a while and reading this post. 
onchange works!

```
<input id="approval"  type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" onchange="Approve(this)">
```

@Mike is right, bootstrap is overwriting onchange and keyup/down. 
But 'onchange()' did the trick!